# jQuery document.ready fired but elements aren't found

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a problem that happens only on a specific computer(FFX 3.6.13,Windows 7,jQuery 1.4.3).
Sometimes document.ready is fired but when trying to get elements to attach the event handlers,the elements don't exist!

the code goes something like this:

```
$(function(){
   window.initStart = true;
   $("#id_of_element").click(function()...);
   window.initEnd = $("#id_of_element");
});
```

the window.initStart/End are there for debugging,sometimes this code runs just fine,but sometimes window.initEnd is just a empty jQuery set(length == 0).
What this means is that document.ready is always fired,but sometimes it is fired **before** elements are available.

Does anybody had this problem? what could the problem be?

Comment: It does not explain *why* this is happening, but have you tried putting the scripts at the end of the document?

Comment: It's only specific to one single computer? Then it's most likely the computer's fault, not your code.

Comment: Could you share your code ? So anybody could test it

Comment: Is your javascript before the closing body tag at the bottom of your document? It's best practice to put it there to get around things like this! You can also try changing document.ready to $(window).load({});

Comment: the code is in the head,it happens only on one computer.

Comment: Jhoannes:i hope it only happens on one computer that is what i am trying to find out,if it does happen only on that computer then,as you said,it is the computer fault.

Answer (score 1):

One way that you could try to get around this would be with using .live instead of .click. The following code

```
$('#idOfDiv').live('click', function() { doStuff(); });
```

will attach the input function to the click event of everything that is dropped on the page with an id of 'idOfDiv' as soon as it makes it to the page. Whereas .click executes immediately, this should be attached no matter what time the divs make it to the page.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There's an [article on SitePoint](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2010/11/03/scripting-loading-and-irony/) that demonstrates how to sense when certain dom elements are available.

Also I know this is a version specific issue, but if you were on Jquery 1.5 the [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) stuff would be useful here.

Comment: I know about this,the code is simple and shouldn't be making problems it is something that happens *sometimes* on a specific machine,the only thing i want to know if it will happen in other computers.